# How to find the class an object is associated to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two ActiceRecord classes:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :b
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
end
```

How do I determine the object to which B is associated to when the associations between A and B are only initialized e.g. at runtime?

I am looking for something like this:

```
b.association => A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would help you but

```
B.reflections
```

...will give you a Hash of associations at class level. You could filter through those.

For example:

```
class Datastream < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dashboard
end

Datastream.reflections
# outputs: {:dashboard=>#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x00000100e21ef8 @macro=:belongs_to, @name=:dashboard, @options={}, @active_record=Datastream(id: integer, dashboard_id: integer, position: integer, feed_id: string, stream_id: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), @collection=false>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Really dirty way:

```
`cat app/models/b.rb | grep 'belongs_to'`.gsub("belongs_to ", "")
```

Just avoid using dynamic data to avoid:

```
; rm -rf *
```

being inserted in there....